# Error when uploading a large number of files to FireBase Hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I'm trying to upload 19,941 files weighing 222 MB to FireBase Hosting. I log in as usual with **firebase login**, then initialize **firebase init** and deploy **firebase deploy**. But when deploying, an error occurs:

```
=== Deploying to 'wowonder-b514c'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[wowonder-b514c]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[wowonder-b514c]: found 19760 files in public
⠹  hosting: adding files to version [16000/19760] (80%)
Error: Task index 10 failed: retries exhausted after 4 attempts, with error: Failed to make request to https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/sites/wowonder-b514c/versions/9b27e5663b5d8853:populateFiles

Error: Task index 10 failed: retries exhausted after 4 attempts, with error: Failed to make request to https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/sites/wowonder-b514c/versions/9b27e5663b5d8853:populateFiles
```

**firebase.json**:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```